# Copying directories in Windows 10

Tags: performance, c, file-system, windows

I wrote a program to copy directories in Windows 10. I have tested copying a directory (696MB) in 3 different ways:

- xcopy: time taken - 52 seconds
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>: time taken - 78 seconds
- My program: time taken - 193 seconds

What can I do to improve the performance of my program to be as fast as xcopy?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int copyfile(const char *inputfile, const char *outputfile);
void CopyDirectory(const char *src_dir, const char *dst_dir);

int main(void)
{
    clock_t t1 = clock();

    // src directory must end with \\*
    /* dst directory must end with \\ */
    CopyDirectory("C:\\Users\\green\\Downloads\\Folder1\\*",
                  "C:\\users\\green\\desktop\\Folder1\\");

    clock_t t2 = clock();
    printf("time elapsed : %.4f secs\n", (double)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    puts("Press any key to continue...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void CopyDirectory(const char *src_dir, const char *dst_dir)
{
    intptr_t hFile;
    struct _finddata_t c_file;

    char *ptr;
    char buf[MAX_PATH + 20];
    char tmp_dir[MAX_PATH + 20];
    char f_name[MAX_PATH + 20];

    strcpy(buf, src_dir);
    ptr = buf + strlen(buf) - 1;

    if ((hFile = _findfirst(src_dir, &c_file)) == -1L) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open directory %s\n", src_dir);
        return;
    }
    CreateDirectoryA(dst_dir, NULL);
    while (_findnext(hFile, &c_file) == 0) {
        if (c_file.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) {
            if (strcmp(c_file.name, "..")) {
                /*......*/
                strcpy(tmp_dir, dst_dir);
                strcat(tmp_dir, c_file.name);
                strcat(tmp_dir, "\\");
                /*......*/
                *ptr = '\0';
                strcat(buf, c_file.name);
                strcat(buf, "\\*");
                CopyDirectory(buf, tmp_dir);
            }
        }
        else {
            strcpy(tmp_dir, dst_dir);
            strcat(tmp_dir, c_file.name);

            *ptr = '\0';
            strcpy(f_name, buf);
            strcat(f_name, "\\");
            strcat(f_name, c_file.name);
            copyfile(f_name, tmp_dir);
            strcpy(tmp_dir, dst_dir);
        }
    }
    _findclose(hFile);
}

int copyfile(const char *inputfile, const char *outputfile)
{
    static FILE *fp_I;
    static FILE *fp_O;

    fp_I = fopen(inputfile, "rb");
    if (!fp_I) {
        perror(inputfile);
        return -1;
    }

    fp_O = fopen(outputfile, "wb");
    if (!fp_O) {
        fclose(fp_I);
        perror(outputfile);
        return -1;
    }

    static size_t nr;
    const static size_t bufsize = 512 * 512;
    static char buf[bufsize];

    while ((nr = fread(buf, 1, bufsize, fp_I)) > 0) {
        fwrite(buf, 1, nr, fp_O);
    }

    fclose(fp_I);
    fclose(fp_O);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you do not even copy ADS and ACLs!!! The truth is that OS has access to lower level structures and buffer size is _optimized_ and crefully chosen (maybe even dynamically according to sector size and media type) and probably bigger than your buffer

Comment: Have you tried to use [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @ChrisWue I tried `CopyFileA()` and the program took 211.9s :):)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what in the world is ADS and ACLs ?

Comment: [Alternate Data Streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) and [Access Control List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). Also note that overlapped I/O **may** greatly increase performance (and, well, multithreading...God knows)

Comment: Don't call ASCII versions of Windows APIs if you need performance. They incur the extra overhead of transforming the strings to Unicode before calling the Unicode version of the API. Letting the kernel handle copying the content of the file should be much faster as it doesn't have to context switch and copy buffers in process memory just to have it copied again into kernel memory.

Comment: Are you [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] as an educational exercise?

Comment: @RubberDuck I am not reinventing the wheel. But sometimes I can't find what i want to perform, and sometimes I find it but I need more functionality so, I do it myself.

Comment: Okay then @machine_1. Do you mind explaining what functionality you need that XCopy doesn't provide?

Comment: @RubberDuck If you want to use xcopy in C code, you have to use `system()`. Also, I often make different versions  of the original function, so that's it.

Comment: That's not a very convincing argument @machine_1. It's okay to reinvent the wheel if you've got good reasons, but I don't think you've got good reasons here. If you're worried about losing portability, hide the calls to system behind an implementation of an abstract class.

Comment: How many files are there in your directory?  When I try to copy a 900MB directory on my machine, it takes 2 seconds.  But that directory is full of relatively big files (mp3 files).  Is your directory full of small files?  Also, is your destination directory empty?  Because for me it takes 14 seconds to delete all of the existing files and only 2 seconds to copy them.  So if the directory is not empty, it takes 16 seconds overall.

Comment: @jsi My directory has a lot of subdirectories. Here lies the problem, but as you can see, xcopy is much faster than my program.

Comment: IMO calling system(xcopy) in this case may be really the best option, with such huge save of time (I dislike system() usage too). Then again, even 1min is a lot, if the source data are under your control, you can probably gain lot more by redesigning the file structure, to have fewer directories/files as source data, then copy will take less time even with current code. Also how often you copy that directory in real life?! Installers do something like that, but only once per install lifetime of app (plus delete for uninstall). I would understand such optimization in case of compiler/builder.

Comment: I'm not on windows (= not answering), ideas only: try in CopyDirectory read the current hFile fully into `std::vector` first, close it, then loop trough the vector. Try unicode variant of `CreateDirectoryA` (how do you even end with "*A" in source? Isn't the win SDK providing `CreateDirectory` macro redirecting to the correct one?). You don't check `CreateDirectoryA` for success.. if it fails, what will happen? With file operations I would be extremely cautious and check everything. I once deleted whole HDD to my friend by our uninstaller, didn't have "install dir" value in registers => "C:\".

Comment: According to MSDN ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx ), `fread` takes as input the buffer, the size, the count and the stream. This means that you're reading 1 byte many times instead of many bytes one time. Try swapping those two values and see if there's any improvement.

Comment: Maybe because you have alot of sub-directories "My directory has a lot of subdirectories" @machine_1 your making lots of calls to CopyDirectory which has to allocate lots of memory `(char[4096+20] * 3?)`, maybe try to `fork()` the process, because you don't really "care" (values don't have to propagate up function call stack) about the return value of CopyDirectory and you can let the child thread do the copying.

Answer (score 2):

Re-architect to do lots of reading, then lots of writing - *then* loop.

OP's code presently reads file A, writes file A, reads file B, writes file B, ...

Reading file A, file B,.... partial file Z and then writing those into a large `buffer` is certainly faster.  Of course it is more complicated as code needs to pick-up where it left off in the middle of file Z.

I first noticed this huge saving BITD when `XCOPY *.*` came out as it read many files first versus the old `COPY *.*`.  This paradigm has been consistently true with my subsequent coding experiences.

A central issue, that unless you get deeper into the DISK I/O, code is limited to *trying* to do what it thinks the file system wants best in order to perform fast.

Using multiple threads (one for reading, one for writing) may help too.

Comment: What is BITD ??

Comment: @machine_1 [BITD](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Back-in-the-Day-(BITD).html)  A time when computers were made of [stone knives and bearskins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfJXd0rSCqo).

Comment: It would be worthy of the bounty to provide some code, you know! I didn't offer the bounty for a textual answer only :)). Answer's prize is +15...

Comment: @machine_1 The amount of quality coding to re-architect this is _significant_, far more than 100 _points_, but a lot of _work_.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore all the C functions and using the windows API calls:  `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, etc.  Then you can specify unbuffered file reads (for larger files), and use asynchronous IO calls to read and write simultaneously, which is particularly handy when copying between two different physical disks.

The hardware solution would be to upgrade to a decent Solid State Drive.